# AVPlayer audio buffering in swift 3 source disconnected observer

Tags: iphone, swift3, xcode8

I have app that plays AAC audio stream. Everything works fine, but when I disconnect stream and connect again after one second audio stop playing after half minute. When i don't reconnect i have error after one- two minutes. To reconnect i must stop AVPlayer and start again. I want to reconnect stream or show message immediately after player stops play music. How can I do that? Moreover i have another question: I convert my code to swift 3 and I have problem with one line:

```
fileprivate var playerItem = AVPlayerItem?()
```

error: cannot invoke initializer without argument
How i can fix that? Maybe this is the problem?

My Radio Player class:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

protocol errorMessageDelegate {
    func errorMessageChanged(_ newVal: String)
}

protocol sharedInstanceDelegate {
    func sharedInstanceChanged(_ newVal: Bool)
}

class RadioPlayer : NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = RadioPlayer()
    var instanceDelegate:sharedInstanceDelegate? = nil
    var sharedInstanceBool = false {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = self.instanceDelegate {
                delegate.sharedInstanceChanged(self.sharedInstanceBool)
            }
        }
    }
    fileprivate var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: Globals.radioURL)!)
 //   fileprivate var playerItem = AVPlayerItem?()
    fileprivate var isPlaying = false

    var errorDelegate:errorMessageDelegate? = nil
    var errorMessage = "" {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = self.errorDelegate {
                delegate.errorMessageChanged(self.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        errorMessage = ""

        let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: Globals.radioURL)!, options: nil)

        let statusKey = "tracks"

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [statusKey], completionHandler: {
            var error: NSError? = nil

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let status: AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: statusKey, error: &error)

                if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded{

                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.sharedInstanceBool = true

                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                    print(error!)
                }

            })


        })

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil,
            using: { notification in
                print("Status: Failed to continue")
                self.errorMessage = NSLocalizedString("STREAM_INTERUPT", comment:"Stream was interrupted")
        })

        print("Initializing new player")

    }

    func resetPlayer() {
        errorMessage = ""

        let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: Globals.radioURL)!, options: nil)

        let statusKey = "tracks"

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [statusKey], completionHandler: {
            var error: NSError? = nil

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let status: AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: statusKey, error: &error)

                if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded{

                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
          //          playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &ItemStatusContext)

                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.sharedInstanceBool = true

                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                    print(error!)
                }

            })
        })
    }

    func bufferFull() -> Bool {
        return bufferAvailableSeconds() > 45.0
    }

    func bufferAvailableSeconds() -> TimeInterval {
        // Check if there is a player instance
        if ((player.currentItem) != nil) {

            // Get current AVPlayerItem
            let item: AVPlayerItem = player.currentItem!
            if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay) {

                let timeRangeArray: NSArray = item.loadedTimeRanges as NSArray
                if timeRangeArray.count < 1 { return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid)) }
                let aTimeRange: CMTimeRange = (timeRangeArray.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).timeRangeValue
         //       let startTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.end)
                let loadedDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.duration)

                return (TimeInterval)(loadedDuration);
            }
            else {
                return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid))
            }
        } 
        else {
            return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid))
        }
    }

    func play() {
        player.play()
        isPlaying = true
        print("Radio is \(isPlaying ? "" : "not ")playing")
    }

    func pause() {
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false
        print("Radio is \(isPlaying ? "" : "not ")playing")
    }

    func currentlyPlaying() -> Bool {
        return isPlaying
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for help ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the second issue `fileprivate var playerItem = AVPlayerItem?()`
write this and it should work `fileprivate var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?`.

For the first issue

> when I disconnect stream and connect again after one second audio stop
>   playing after half minute. When i don't reconnect i have error after
>   one- two minutes. To reconnect i must stop AVPlayer and start again. I
>   want to reconnect stream or show message immediately after player
>   stops play music. How can I do that?

I don't get what's wrong ? You pause the player by pressing the button then you press the button again and after one - two minutes it stops by itself ?

I have tested the same class today and it works just fine, even after the connection is lost to the server (when the connection resumes you can click the play button and it will play)

I'll leave you my code here, give it a try

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

protocol errorMessageDelegate {
    func errorMessageChanged(newVal: String)
}

protocol sharedInstanceDelegate {
    func sharedInstanceChanged(newVal: Bool)
}



class RadioPlayer : NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = RadioPlayer()
    var instanceDelegate:sharedInstanceDelegate? = nil
    var sharedInstanceBool = false {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = self.instanceDelegate {
                delegate.sharedInstanceChanged(newVal: self.sharedInstanceBool)
            }
        }
    }
    private var player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(string: "<# YOUR STREAM HERE #>")! as URL)
    private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    private var isPlaying = false

    var errorDelegate:errorMessageDelegate? = nil
    var errorMessage = "" {
        didSet {
            if let delegate = self.errorDelegate {
                delegate.errorMessageChanged(newVal: self.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        errorMessage = ""

        let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: NSURL(string: "<# YOUR STREAM HERE #>")! as URL, options: nil)

        let statusKey = "tracks"

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [statusKey], completionHandler: {

            var error: NSError? = nil

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let status: AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: statusKey, error: &error)

                if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded{

                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.sharedInstanceBool = true

                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                    print(error!)
                }

            })

        })

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil,
            using: { notification in
                print("Status: Failed to continue")
                self.errorMessage = "Stream was interrupted"
        })

        print("Initializing new player")

    }

    func resetPlayer() {
        errorMessage = ""

        let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: NSURL(string: "<# YOUR STREAM HERE #>")! as URL, options: nil)

        let statusKey = "tracks"

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [statusKey], completionHandler: {
            var error: NSError? = nil

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let status: AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: statusKey, error: &error)

                if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded{

                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                    //playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &ItemStatusContext)

                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.sharedInstanceBool = true

                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                    print(error!)
                }

            })
        })
    }

    func bufferFull() -> Bool {
        return bufferAvailableSeconds() > 45.0
    }

    func bufferAvailableSeconds() -> TimeInterval {
        // Check if there is a player instance
        if ((player.currentItem) != nil) {

            // Get current AVPlayerItem
            let item: AVPlayerItem = player.currentItem!
            if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay) {

                let timeRangeArray: NSArray = item.loadedTimeRanges as NSArray
                if timeRangeArray.count < 1 { return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid)) }
                let aTimeRange: CMTimeRange = (timeRangeArray.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).timeRangeValue
                //let startTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.end)
                let loadedDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.duration)
                return (TimeInterval)(loadedDuration)
            }
            else {
                return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid))
            }
        }
        else {
            return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid))
        }
    }

    func play() {
        player.play()
        isPlaying = true
        print("Radio is \(isPlaying ? "" : "not ")playing")
    }

    func pause() {
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false
        print("Radio is \(isPlaying ? "" : "not ")playing")
    }

    func currentlyPlaying() -> Bool {
        return isPlaying
    }

}
```